# PHP preg_split with two delimiters and capture only one

Tags: php, regex, delimiter, preg-split

Really poor at regular expressions, sorry in advance!

I've tried my best to work out how to split a string into a array with two delimiters and still capture one and include it in the final array. `preg_split` seems ideal for this but my regular expression is letting me down.

If for example, I've the string `foo = bar AND bar=foo`; I want to split the string at either a space, or the `=` character BUT keep the `=` so the array would look like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => foo
    [1] => =
    [2] => bar
    [3] => AND
    [4] => bar
    [5] => =
    [6] => foo
)
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => foo
    [1] => 
    [2] => =
    [3] => 
    [4] => bar
    [5] => AND
    [6] => bar
    [7] => =
    [8] => foo
)
```

I've got here with this code (in PHP):

```
<!doctype html>
<?php

$string = 'foo = bar AND bar=foo';

$array = preg_split('/ +|(=)/', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

?>
<pre>
<?php

print_r($array);

?>
</pre>
```

I'd really appreciate any help you guys can give, thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` flag:

```
$string = 'foo = bar AND bar=foo';
$array = preg_split('/ +|(=)/', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Now, [this outputs](http://viper-7.com/rztbU5):

```
Array
(
    [0] => foo
    [1] => =
    [2] => bar
    [3] => AND
    [4] => bar
    [5] => =
    [6] => foo
)
```

Comment: You know sometimes, I truly am a douche! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Either use [`PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY`](http://php.net/preg_split) to nuke the "empty" matches:

```
$array = preg_split('/ +|(=)/', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Or, [change the regex](http://php.net/regexp.reference.escape) such that it does not produce empty matches:

```
$array = preg_split('/ +|(?<!\G)(=)/', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```