# PHP preg_split with two delimiters unless a delimiter is within quotes

Tags: php, regex, delimiter, preg-split

Further on from my previous question about [`preg_split`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11867342/php-preg-split-with-two-delimiters-and-capture-only-one) which was answers super fast, thanks to nick; I would really like to extend the scenario to no split the string when a delimiter is within quotes. For example:

If I have the string `foo = bar AND bar=foo OR foobar="foo bar"`, I'd wish to split the sting on every space or `=` character but include the `=` character in the returned array (which works great currently), but I don't want to split the string either of the delimiters are within quotes.

I've got this so far:

```
<!doctype html>
<?php

$string = 'foo = bar AND bar=foo';

$array = preg_split('/ +|(=)/', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

?>
<pre>
<?php

print_r($array);

?>
</pre>
```

Which gets me:

```
Array
(
    [0] => foo
    [1] => =
    [2] => bar
    [3] => AND
    [4] => bar
    [5] => =
    [6] => foo
)
```

But if I changed the string to:

```
$string = 'foo = bar AND bar=foo OR foobar = "foo bar"';
```

I'd really like the array to be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => foo
    [1] => =
    [2] => bar
    [3] => AND
    [4] => bar
    [5] => =
    [6] => foo
    [6] => OR
    [6] => foobar
    [6] => =
    [6] => "foo bar"
)
```

Notice the `"foo bar"` wasn't split on the space because it's in quotes?

Really not sure how to do this within the RegEx or if there is even a better way but all your help would be very much appreciated!

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to do this by adding quoted strings as a delimiter a-la

```
"(.*?)"| +|(=)
```

The quoted part will be captured.  It seems like this is a bit tenuous and I did not test it extensively, but it at least works on your example.

Comment: Good idea. This should work unless quoted strings span multiple lines.

Comment: Awesome, I've added single quote check too [`'/"(.*?)"|(=)|\'(.*?)\'| +/'`] - this exactly fits the bill of what I needed. However, for others looking for a similar answer, this method strips the quotes, Tim's keep them in. This way works best for me but Tim's way is exceptional too! Thank you both!

Comment: @JonathonDavidOates if you want to keep the quotes just put the parentheses outside of the quotes (e.g. `(".*?")`).  I thought your sample array left them off but I see that it doesn't.

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
$array = preg_split('/(?: +|(=))(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)/', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

The

```
(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)
```

part is a [lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) making sure that there is an even number of quote characters ahead in the string, therefore it will fail if the current position is between quotes:

```
(?=      # Assert that the following can be matched:
 (?:     # A group containing...
  [^"]*" #  any number of non-quote characters followed by one quote
  [^"]*" #  the same (to ensure an even number of quotes)
 )*      # ...repeated zero or more times,
 [^"]*   # followed by any number of non-quotes
 $       # until the end of the string
)
```

Comment: Not the OP, but trying to understand this. The idea is that if there are not an even number of quote characters, you're currently in the middle of a quoted section and should not be splitting, right?

Comment: @DragoonWraith: Right. I have assumed that we're not expecting any escaped quotes in our strings. Those could be worked into the regex, too, but I didn't want to make this more complicated than necessary.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. Very nice; I was all set to comment that I didn't think RegEx could handle this. I never would have thought to use lookahead for an even number of quotes to ensure we're not in a quoted section.

Answer (score 0):

**But why bother splitting?**

After a look at this old question, this simple solution comes to mind, using a `preg_match_all` rather than a `preg_split`. We can use this simple regex to specify what we want:

```
"[^"]*"|\b\w+\b|=
```

See [online demo](http://regex101.com/r/lX1wQ4).