# preg_split with two patterns (one of them quoted)

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I would like to split a string in PHP containing quoted and unquoted substrings.
Let's say I have the following string:

```
"this is a string" cat dog "cow"
```

The splitted array should look like this:

```
array (  
[0] => "this is a string"  
[1] => "cat"  
[2] => "dog"  
[3] => "cow"  
)
```

I'm struggling a bit with regex and I'm wondering if it is even possible to achieve with just one regex/preg_split-Call...

The first thing I tried was:

```
[[:blank:]]*(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)[[:blank:]]*
```

But this splits only array[0] and array[3] correctly - the rest is splitted on a per character base.

Then I found this link:
[PHP preg_split with two delimiters unless a delimiter is within quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11873240/php-preg-split-with-two-delimiters-unless-a-delimiter-is-within-quotes)

```
(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)
```

This seems to me as a good startingpoint. However the result in my example is the same as with the first regex.

I tried combining both - first the one for quoted strings and then a second sub-regex which should ommit quoted string (therefore the [^"]):

```
(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)|[[:blank:]]*([^"].*[^"])[[:blank:]]*
```

Therefore 2 questions:

1. Is it even possible to achieve what I want with just one regex/preg_split-Call?
2. If yes, I would appreciate a hint on how to assemble the regex correctly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since matches cannot overlap, you could use `preg_match_all` like this:

```
preg_match_all('/"[^"]*"|\S+/', $input, $matches);
```

Now `$matches[0]` should contain what you are looking for. The regex will first try to match a quoted string, and then stop. If that doesn't do it it will just collect as many non-whitespace characters as possible. Since alternations are tried from left to right, the quoted version takes precedence.

**EDIT:** This will not get rid of the quotes though. To do this, you could use capturing groups:

```
preg_match_all('/(?|"([^"]*)"|(\S+))/', $input, $matches);
```

Now `$matches[1]` will contain exactly what you are looking for. The `(?|` is there so that both capturing groups end up at the same index.

**EDIT 2:** Since you were asking for a `preg_split` solution, that is also possible. We can use a lookahead, that asserts that the space is followed by an even number of quotes (up until the end of the string):

```
$result = preg_split('/\s+(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*$)/', $input);
```

Of course, this will not get rid of the quotes, but that can easily be done in a separate step.

Comment: Thanks a lot! As I need this for MATCH-AGAINST-Validation in MySQL, preg_split('/\s+(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*$)/', $input) is exactly what i was looking for

Comment: just did some further testing: the preg_split regex stops working as soon as the input string is altered like: cat dog "this is a string" "cow"  
However the "/(?|"([^"]*)"|(\S+))/" with preg_match_all does the job.

Comment: @Stefan huh, that's odd the split solution works with that string for me, too. but I'm glad you could get the other one to work.